# LoF内で外部URLとPDFのリンクが競合する

Tags: latex

LaTeXで画像のCaption内にhyperrefパッケージでリンク付きのURLを貼っているのですが，List of Figures内ではPDF内の図へリンクされてしまい，`https://google.com`にリンクされません．後者にリンクさせたいのですが何か良い方法はありますでしょうか．

追記：基本は内部リンクを残しながら，`https://google.com`のところだけ外部リンクとしたいです．

```
\documentclass[a4j, fleqn, dvipdfmx]{jarticle}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{image.jpg}
        \caption{画像は\url{https://google.com}から．}
    \end{figure}
    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image: 生成PDF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

図目次に出力されるキャプション内のURL部を外部リンクとして機能するようにするだけであれば、hyperrefパッケージを`linktoc=none`オプション付きで読み込めば実現できそうです。

```
\usepackage[linktoc=none]{hyperref}
```

これにより「目次類の各項目を、当該項目の位置にジャンプする内部リンクにする」hyperrefの機能（デフォルトで有効）が無効化され、普通の目次以外の箇所に`画像は\url{https://google.com}から`と書いたのと同様の出力結果を得ることができます。

---

別解として、LuaLaTeXを使用すればハイパーリンクの入れ子がサポートされ、特に工夫をせずとも「目次内の項目全体としては該当箇所への内部リンク、項目中のリンク箇所だけは外部リンクとして機能させる」ことができるようです。

```
%#!lualatex
\documentclass[a4j, fleqn]{ltjarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption{画像は\url{https://google.com}から．}
    \end{figure}
    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: `[linktoc=none]`で読み込むとLoFから図に飛ぶリンクも消えてしまうのですが，LuaLaTeXを使わない限り，LoF内で｢URLをクリックしたら外部リンクへ飛ぶ｣と｢URL以外をクリックしたら図に飛ぶ｣を両立させるのは厳しいですかね…

Comment: 内部リンクと外部リンクを両立したかったのですね。その意図は現在の質問文からは読み取れないので追記をおすすめします。

Comment: platex+dvipdfmxでの両立ですが、簡単ではなさそうです。hyperrefにnestingオプションがありますが、マニュアルによればほとんどのドライバがサポートしていません。最近LaTeXチームがLaTeX本体の大改修を行う中で開発している新しいpdfmanagementだけはサポートしているようですが、手許だとpLaTeXでは期待通り動いていません。いずれにしても、あまりに新しい機能なので、当面は動作不安定なのではないかと思います。

Comment: wtsnjpさんの解答を元に自分で調べたところ，`[linktoc=page]`で完全とはいかないまでもある程度は自分の理想となりました．ご回答ありがとうございました．